# sqrt, cbrt - what if don't want squared or cubed root, but any root?

Tags: java, clojure

In maths libraries in Java and Clojure you can usually find a power (or exponent) function. In `java.lang.Math` it is `exp`. But I haven't been able to find a generic function for finding *any* root. In `java.lang.Math` you can get the squared root with `sqrt`, and the cubed root with `cbrt`. What if I want to find the 4th root? I am looking for an implementation or the formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Math.pow(a, 1/b)` to compute the bth root of a.

Comment: Most accessible answer to what really is a Maths question.

Comment: @ChrisMurphy How is this "more accessible" than the identical answer by noisesmith?

Comment: More people can read Java than Clojure, and does not have the shortcut of missing out the `1` in `1` over `6`, which is extra detail beyond the question. It is short and sufficient.

Comment: @ChrisMurphy So if you didn't want a Clojure answer, why did you tag your question as [tag:clojure]?

Comment: Well if the answer was at all involved then I would have far preferred to read it in Clojure. But I didn't know the answer would be a one liner at the time of asking the question.

Answer (score 7):

You can get a root by getting the reciprocal power.

```clj
;; Clojure shorthand to get the reciprocal
+user=> (/ 6)
1/6

;; 6th root
+user=> (Math/pow 42 (/ 6))
1.8644105355008191

;; verifying the identity
+user=> (Math/pow (Math/pow 42 (/ 6)) 6)
42.00000000000005
```

Comment: `(/ 6)` seems to be the same as `(/ 1 6)`. So the 1 is assumed. Can you point to a reference so I can understand that a bit better?

Comment: From `/` docs: "If no denominators are supplied, returns 1/numerator,
else returns numerator divided by all of the denominators".

Comment: Show me where the `/` docs are and I'll add a SEE ALSO to the [quot docs](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/quot). `/` docs are impossible to google.

Comment: @ChrisMurphy Here is the ClojureDocs page for [`/`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/_fs). With DuckDuckGo, you can find it easily using the search query `!clojure /`.

Comment: @ChrisMurphy Just checked the [bangs list](https://duckduckgo.com/bang?q=clojure) again; looks like the `!clj` bang has been added recently, so now you can just use `!clj /`. :)